# How to stretch image in android appcelerator app to full width, but keep aspect ratio?

Tags: android, image, titanium, appcelerator

So I'm trying to view image in appcelerator android app, but I always get either image that fills whole screen, or image that has right aspect ration, but is not stretched to full width.

This code should show image stretched to full width, but keep aspect ratio, but it does not.

```
        var designView = Ti.UI.createView({
        width:Ti.UI.FILL,
        backgroundColor:"#042D40"
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the height too!

```
var designView = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    backgroundColor:"#042D40"
});
```

Also, you should use `ImageView` for an image. So use the same `size` properties for the ImageView

Comment: Hello thanks this worked, the problem was that I did not use ImageView.